# How to display a local Bitmap to SimpleDraweeView

Tags: android, fresco

I have a SimpleDraweeView and can display an image correctly by:

```
SimpleDraweeView draweeView = (SimpleDraweeView) findViewById(R.id.hotel_image_view);
            draweeView.setImageURI(uri);
```

but sometimes i want to use a local image like @drawable not from a  URL, but `setImageBitmap` or `setImageResource` can't be used:

```
draweeView.setImageBitmap(R.drawable.test_image);
```

How could i do this? Use an `ImageView` under `SimperDrweeView` hide/show by some condition to use local image? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a @drawable in a Fresco image request. This is one way:

```
ImageRequest request =
    ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithResourceId(R.drawable.test_image)
                       .build();
DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
    .setImageRequest(request)
    .setOldController(draweeView.getController())
    .build();
draweeView.setController(controller);
```

Comment: draweeView is SimpleDraweeView, seems no setImageRequest. Any suggestions? thx!

Comment: Correct, I got mixed up. Edited the answer.

Comment: Hi @tyronen, R.id.hotel_image_view is SimpleDraweeView, i didn't see the code in your answer call my local bitmap, like R.drawable.test_image.

Comment: Another typo. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

can't you try `draweeView.setUri(UriUtil.getUriForResourceId(R.drawable.test_image);`

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's so late but may help someone searching a simple answer.
You should call this: draweeView.setActualImageResource(R.drawable.your_image)